# Google App Engine SDK on Windows?

Tags: google-app-engine

It is announced here
New App Engine Launcher for Windows
http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/09/app-engine-sdk-125-released-for-python.html

But it's only for Python not for Java ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the launcher for Java - the [eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/download.html) works on all three platforms, and includes all the functionality the Python launcher has.